# How can I return a HttpStatusCode from an IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, http-status-codes

I am coding a `C# WebApi 2` webservice, and I have a question in regards to returning a `HttpStatusCode` from an `IQueryable<T>` webservice function.

If a web service function returns a single object, the following can easily be used:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetItem(int id)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Any object");
}
```

In the following situation, I am not sure on how to return a specified `HttpStatusCode`:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetItems()
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Any object");
}
```

Can I please have some help with this?

Answer (score 6):

You can throw a `HttpResponseException` with the appropriate statuscode

```
public IQueryable<T> GetItems()
{
   throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { Content = new StringContent("Any object") });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the the first situation, you are still going to be returning the object in the `Content` method, e.g:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetItem(int id)
{
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Any object");
}
```

When you execute that method, you would see a `"Any object"` returned to the client. In Web API 2 `IHttpActionResult` is essentially a fancy factory around `HttpResponseMessage`. If you ignore that the return type of the method is `IHttpActionResult`, you can return an `IQueryable` by replacing "Any object" with the queryable, e.g:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetItem(int id)
{ 
    IQueryable<object> results;
    return Ok(results);
}
```

Some more info on action results in Web API can be found here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results